# what is the exact meaning of the term "NoSql"?

Tags: mongodb, nosql

In case of the scalable database, what is the exact meaning of the term "NoSQL"?  Why are we calling  "NoSQL"? What is the reason?
Please explain me.

Answer (score 0):

1SQL is a relational database meaning that you must define the data first. In SQL, you must create a table with a value and a type. An example of this is creating a field called 'firstname' with a type of VARCHAR. In NoSQL, the database doesn't follow a pre-determined schema. An example would be MongoDB. MongoDB uses a JSON-like document to store data. Let's say you want to store a user which has other sub-fields in it. One user can just have a name and email while another user may have a name, email, and date.

```
{
  "users" : [ 
    {
      "name" : "John Doe",
      "email": "JDoe@server.com"
    },
    {
      "name" : "John Doe",
      "email": "JDoe@server.com",
      "date" : "2-28-2018"
    }
  ]
}
```

in comparison with this SQL-like table where every user has a premade structure

```html
<table style="width:100%" border="1px">
  <tr>
    <th>name</th>
    <th>email</th> 
    <th>date</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>John Doe</td>
    <td>JDoe@server.com</td> 
    <td>null</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jane Doe</td>
    <td>JaneD@server.com</td> 
    <td>2-28-2018</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

If this was to be done in SQL, a table with a name, email, and date field would have to be created even if a user did not possess one of those fields. As a result, a NoSQL database can offer more versatility versus a conventional relational database.

[See this article for further details about SQL vs NoSQL](https://medium.com/xplenty-blog/the-sql-vs-nosql-difference-mysql-vs-mongodb-32c9980e67b2)

Answer (score 0):

Term NoSQL represents non relational database systems encapsulating features of flexibility into database schema design by organizing storage of data as lightweight BSON documents as opposed to conventional storage of data across rows into database tables following relational model design. Unlike database systems using SQL as a query language NoSQL database systems don't have full support of database transactions  but into upcoming version of MongoDB, version
4.0 transactions will be a part of NOSQL database system .

NoSQL database system such as MongoDB doesn't have commands to perform manipulation of data stored across collections belonging to database unlike SQL consisting of commands such as SELECT,INSERT,DELETE,UPDATE etc which belongs to DML (Data Manipulation Language) component of SQL. Unlike database systems using SQL as query language ,NOSQL database systems being non relational databases don't support join operations alternatively relational model of data is defined using embedded documents  which minimizes round trip to database servers while retrieval of data stored across collections belonging to database.

Hence due to such major differences into their methodologies term NOSQL is defined to represent behaviour of database systems not using SQL as query language